# Dapper and FBCommand

Tags: c#, firebird, dapper

I have a question about how to write SQL's with Dapper.

Now I use something like this:

```
resultObject result;
String sqlCmd = String.Format("select * from SOME_PROCEDURE('{0}',{1},{2})", Param1, Param2, Param3);
result = FbConnection1.Query<resultObject>(sqlCmd, null).ToList();
```

But now I see that it is not so clean, And I found a `FBCommand` which allow me to use

```
FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("select * from SOME_PROCEDURE(@param1, @param2)");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", FbDbType.Integer).Value = value1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", FbDbType.Integer).Value = value2;
```

I don't know how to user Dapper with FBCommand, is it possible ? Or maybe using `String.Format` for building SQL is good way?

Comment: Using `string.Format` is not only 'not clean', it also allows for SQL injection and therefor a bad practice! And Dapper works with Firebird, see https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel. That's what I was looked for. 
I don't know how i could miss it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* there is a corresponding `FbConnection`, and *if* that connection is a standard ADO.NET implementation, and *if* it supports standard parameters, then yes, you could try doing:

```
using(FbConnection conn = ...)
{
    var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(
       "select * from SOME_PROCEDURE(@value1, @value2)",
       new { value1, value2 }).ToList();
    // ...
}
```

You could also try:

```
using(FbConnection conn = ...)
{
    var data = conn.Query<SomeType>("SOME_PROCEDURE",
       new { param1 = value1, param2 = value2 },
       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
    // ...
}
```